# .net wpf textbox capacity

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a multi line enabled text box in my application where user can copy paste text .
I need to know the capacity of text box - so that I can show a custom text in the text box if user exceeds that limit.

Comment: I suspect that if there is a maximum, it is much larger than you should be using it for anyway...

Answer (score 1):

the length of the textbox text is the length of the text property, which is the [length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) of a string, which is defined by an integer. you would need to overflow an integer, so you can compare against Int32.MaxValue if you want, but more likely you'll have an exception thrown.